# SQL Server : case without a null return

Tags: sql-server, select

I have the following SQL Server code:

```
declare @n_count_pr int, @n_count_err int, @v_out_pr varchar(100);

begin
   set @n_count_pr = (select count (*) from table_PR)
   set @n_count_err = (select count (*) from table_err)

   if (@n_count_err > 0 AND @n_count_pr > 0)  
      set @v_out_pr = 'Output 1'
   else if (@n_count_err > 0 AND @n_count_pr = 0) 
      set @v_out_pr = 'Output 2'

   print @v_out_pr
end;
```

It works perfectly fine, but I need a different structure.

I need a simple select that do the same thing.

Can you help me?

In the procedure above I have **only** two outputs an nothing else.
If there is any other output other than output 1 and output 2 it  should be discarded.

It's like:

if i = a then output 1
else if i = b then output 2

But I don't have an else, so every other option i=c or i = d, I don't care. I want to discard those options.

If I did want other options I would do this:

```
   if (@n_count_err > 0 AND @n_count_pr > 0)  
      set @v_out_pr = 'Output 1'
   else if (@n_count_err > 0 AND @n_count_pr = 0) 
      set @v_out_pr = 'Output 2'
   else
      set @v_out_pr = 'any other option'
```

--Found a solution :)

```
select bit from 
     (SELECT CASE 
        WHEN  (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TABLE_ERR) > 0 AND (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TABLE_PR) > 0 THEN 'OUTPUT 1'
        WHEN  (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TABLE_ERR) > 0 AND (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TABLE_PR) = 0 THEN 'OUTPUT 2'
        ELSE null
        END as bit) Mytable
        where bit is not null
```

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not a code translation service. YOU do the translating, we (maybe) try help fix whatever your produced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN  (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TABLE_ERR) > 0 AND (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TABLE_PR) > 0 THEN 'OUTPUT 1'
        WHEN  (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TABLE_ERR) > 0 AND (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TABLE_PR) = 0 THEN 'OUTPUT 2'
        ELSE ''
        END
```

Comment: I have a small problem with this solution, when both cases are false the case returns null. That doesn't work for me. When both cases are false, the query must return nothing.

Comment: Added ELSE Part in CASE Statement that will return empty string if both case failed

Comment: What about exit case without return? Like a select a table with no data. Is it possible?

Comment: I need a select that can only return Output 1 or Output 2. Can't return null or other. Just those two strings. It's like an if without an else.

Comment: Sorry but I am still not understanding your requirement, can you update your question with sample output

Comment: if you don't want else part then it will return null whenever condition fails. this is expected behaviour.

Comment: Found a solution! :) Can you see what I meant? :) Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @user2903517 your awesome bro :)

Comment: Had a little help from my friend ! ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116710/discussion-between-jaydipj-and-user2903517).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT IIF(x.cnt1 > 0 AND y.cnt2 > 0, 'Output 1', 
          IIF(x.cnt1 = 0 AND y.cnt2 > 0, 'Output 2', NULL) AS Output
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_PR) AS x(cnt1)
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_err) AS y(cnt2)
```

Comment: It doesn't worked out "Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Incorrect syntax near '>'."

Comment: @user2903517 Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN T.C1 > 0 AND T.C2 > 0 THEN 'OutPut1'
             WHEN T.C1 > 0 AND T.C2 = 0 THEN 'OutPut2'
    END AS Col
FROM    ( SELECT    T1.C1 ,
                    T2.C2
      FROM      ( SELECT    COUNT(*) AS C1
                  FROM      table_ERR
                ) AS T1
                CROSS JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS C2
                             FROM   table_PR
                           ) AS T2
    ) AS T;
```

Comment: Thank you, nice to know there are different ways to solve this kind of  "problems".